# Pillow black & white image scaling does not working

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Lets say I have am creating B&W 32*32 image with 4 white pixels

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros([32, 32])
img[4:6, 1:3] = 1
Image.fromarray(img, 'L').resize([1024, 1024], Image.LANCZOS).show()
```

I got completely black picture with all image resampling methods. Don't understand what is wrong here.  *I have tried also `img[4:, 1:] = 1` with same result.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want this:

```
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np 

img = np.zeros((32, 32),np.uint8) 
img[4:6, 1:3] = 255 
Image.fromarray(img, 'L').resize((1024, 1024), Image.LANCZOS).save('result.png')
```

[image]